# Issue of Primary key in TypeORM

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs, typeorm, typeorm-datamapper

I have one `BaseEntity` which is common for multiple modules. so I have created some common column in this entity class. all the classes will extend this class.

```
export abstract class BaseEntity {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
    id: string;

    @CreateDateColumn({ type: 'timestamp', default: () => 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP' })
    createdAt: Date;

    @UpdateDateColumn({ type: 'timestamp', default: () => 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP' })
    modifiedAt: Date;

    @DeleteDateColumn({ type: 'timestamp' })
    deletedAt: Date;
}
```

my `Certificate` class is extending `BaseEntity`. now I want to generate value of `certificateNo` automatically.

```
Entity({ name: 'certificate' })
export class Certificate extends BaseEntity {


    @ApiProperty()
    @Generated('increment')
    certificateNo: string;

    @ApiProperty()
    @Column({ type: 'varchar', length: 100 })
    requestStatus: RequestStatus;

    @ApiProperty()
    @Column({ type: 'varchar', length: 100 })
    sponser: string;
}
```

in the certificateNo column as soon as I put @Column() decorator it gives error. otherwise this column does not get created in database. DB is postgres.

```
    @ApiProperty()
    @Column()   //if I write @Column() error comes. If I dont write ,column not created in DB
    @Generated('increment')
    certificateNo: string;
```

Error is:-

```
[Nest] 24080   - 12/01/2021, 12:59:35 PM   [ExceptionHandler] syntax error at or near "NOT" +4ms
QueryFailedError: syntax error at or near "NOT"
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should specify a correct column type for the "certificateNo" property. See below:

```
@Entity({ name: "certificate" })
export class Certificate extends BaseEntity {

  @Column({type: "integer"})
  @Generated("increment")
  certificateNo: number;

  @Column({ type: "varchar", length: 100 })
  requestStatus: string;

  @Column({ type: "varchar", length: 100 })
  sponser: string;
}
```